# Is there a way to find the first digits of a number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is there a way to find the first digits of a number?

For example, the largest known prime is $2^{43,112,609}-1$, and I did sometime before a induction to find the first digit of a prime like that. But, is there a way to find the first digits of a number?

To find the last x digits is easy, just calculate it mod $10^x$, but we can do something about the first ones?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to know the first digit?

Comment: It's the middle ones that are difficult.

Comment: @JavaMan, well, is just curiosity too, but I think it can be applied to study some numbers ^^.

Comment: @RossMillikan, I think you're right.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you want is $10$ to the power the fractional part of $43,112,609 \log_{10}2\approx 0.50033$, then $10^.50033\approx 3.1646$ so the leading digits are $316.$  [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E43112609)confirms $31647$

Comment: Thx Ross, this works. Unfortunally André had deleted his answer. Thx André too.

Comment: You just need to be careful and make sure that the rounding errors involved are not too much. Getting the first digit of pi raised to the 10^18th power would be hard.